# Need date in "dd-mm-yyyy" format in JSON

Tags: json, rest, openedge, progress-4gl

I need to give date in **"dd-mm-yyyy"** format in REST API. But the API response always comes in **"yyyy-mm-dd"** format even if i changed the format of date field to "99-99-9999". It seems it always gives date in ISO 8601 format no matter what format i choose.

I checked session:date-format and it's already dmy. "write-json()" method also has the same problem. But i only need it in REST webservice. Progress verison: 11.3.
Please see this for more clarification:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttdate
FIELD fdate AS DATE FORMAT "99-99-9999".

CREATE ttdate.
ASSIGN ttdate.fdate = TODAY.

CREATE ttdate.
ASSIGN ttdate.fdate = TODAY - 15.

TEMP-TABLE ttdate:WRITE-JSON("file", "D:/ttdate.json", YES).
```

> {"ttdate": [
>      {
>       "fdate": "2019-02-19"
>     },
>     {
>       "fdate": "2019-02-04"
>     }
>   ]}

In **JSON**, it always gives in YYYY-MM-DD no matter what format i choose. Please don't suggest to use string it will be a huge pain for me to use string.Please note that I am concerned about date format in JSONs only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always keep it simple/force it as a character instead of a date:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE dt AS DATE        NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE c  AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO FORMAT "x(12)".

dt = TODAY.

c = STRING(DAY(dt),"99") + "-" + STRING(MONTH(dt),"99") + "-" + STRING(YEAR(dt), "9999").

DISPLAY c .
```

> 31-01-2019

However, this really works for me, for this use case (displaying).

```
SESSION:DATE-FORMAT = "dmy".
DISP TODAY FORMAT "99-99-9999".
```

Comment: I have added sample code in question, please see that. Date format works on progress client(editor) no problem, but my concern is about date format in JSONs. I couldn't get the date format i wanted in JSON.

Comment: @Mahesh A workaround is still to switch to character for the field

Answer (score 0):

@Jensd first solution sounds like what you will need in your case. When using the WRITE-JSON method, I don't think you have any control over the format of the data. In cases where the other end needs very specific formats for data, a string is sometimes the only way to get it.

Comment: I can't comment yet on other users comments and I wanted to be sure to include the added info about write-json.

Comment: You are right, it seems we don't have any control over the format of the data while using WRITE-JSON. I went with @Jensd advice at the end.